# Will neutering a kitten make him less able to protect himself?

Tags: cats

My kitten, 5 months old, spends 12 hours inside the home & 12 hours outside. There are stray dogs, kids etc who try to scare him but as of now he is able to well handle himself.

Will neutering him reduce his aggression & thereby reduce his ability to protect himself? He is not particularly a very aggressive or fighting cat, but he can handle himself.

What other behaviour changes can I expect after neutering?

Answer (score 4):

While neutering will make him less likely to *start* fights (because he's not competing for females and will likely be less territorial), it will not affect his ability to defend himself.

[The ASPCA](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/general-pet-care/spayneuter-your-pet) some additional information about neutering and its effects on personality and behaviour.